Compare workflow/moderation state in hook_entity_update()
We have a content moderation workflow with 'published', 'draft', 'submitted' and 'returned'.
I am trying to detect changes to the moderation state with hook_node_update().
function mymodule_node_update(NodeInterface $node): void {
  /** @var \Drupal\node\NodeInterface $original_node */
  $original_node = $node->original;
  $old_state = $original_node->get('moderation_state')->getString();
  $new_state = $node->get('moderation_state')->getString();
  dpm("Presave: State change from $old_state to $new_state");
}

When a node with a forward 'draft' revision is updated, and the state changes to e.g. 'submitted', the following happens:
The $new_state always has the correct value.
However, the $old_state is always 'published'.
It seems the ->original does not contain the most recent latest revision, but the most recent published revision.
How would we compare with the most recent latest revision instead?

The content_moderation_notifications module uses hook_entity_presave() to load the latest revision, and attach it to the entity. See https://git.drupalcode.org/project/content_moderation_notifications/-/blob/a2a2f0f67e1573ece66a9c09ddd87d3213796867/content_moderation_notifications.module#L73
I wonder if this is really needed or if there is a simpler way.

There is also hook_entity_revision_create(). But it is useless, both arguments have the latest moderation state as from after the update.
